# How to do animation on scroll in js on both ways (top/bottom)

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I created a little aniamtion in JS by using bounding client. Once I scroll down until the text/content appears, I change its opacity to 1 by applying ".active" from CSS. And when I scroll up above the element again, opacity changes back to 0 (because ".active" gets taken away).

The problem is I want to make the same thing happen when I scroll up to the content element from below. Once the user goes below the content element, opacity should go to 0, then when they scroll back up (so the content element is again in view), opacity should go to 1. So it makes the animation work in both directions, something like on [scrollrevealjs](https://scrollrevealjs.org/)'s front page.

```
document.addEventListener('scroll',()=>{
  let content = document.querySelector('.text');
  let contentPositiontop = content.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  let screenPosition = window.innerHeight ;
  if (contentPositiontop < screenPosition){   
    content.classList.add('active');                                                                
  }
  else{
    content.classList.remove('active');
  }
});

.text{
  transform: translateX(700px) translateY(1000px);
  font-family: Inter;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  position: absolute;
}

.active{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You just need to check the height of the bottom of the content element as well as the top.**

(For the top, we needed to add in the screen height (window.innerHeight) because we were comparing its position to the bottom of the screen. We don't need this for the bottom because we are comparing its position to the top of the screen, which has a vertical position of 0.)

**When both the bottom and the top are in range, we show the content element.**

(If the content element's height were greater than the height of the screen for some reason, you would have to choose values between 0 and window.innerHeight to use to trigger the transition.)

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll',() => {
  const
    content = document.querySelector('.text'),
    top = content.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    bottom = content.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
  if (top < innerHeight && bottom > 0){
    content.classList.add('active');
  }
  else{
    content.classList.remove('active');
  }
});
```

```css
  .spacer{ height: 104vh; }
  .text{ height: 100vh; background: blue; transform: translateX(20px); opacity: 0; transition: all 2s ease; }
  .active{ opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<div class="spacer"> </div>
<div class="text"></div>
<div class="spacer"> </div>
.
```

Comment: thank you it works,but could you explain me why did i had to use bottom>0?What does this 0 present and stand for

Comment: We want to trigger the animation when any part of the content element appears on the screen, so we care about the moment when the top of element touches the bottom of the screen, and vice versa. Zero (0) represents the top of the screen at any moment in time, and further down the screen, the number gets higher (which may seem backwards, but you can see it is true if you put `console.log(bottom)` in your script and scroll up and down.) This is also why we use `top < innerHeight`, because 0 (top of screen position) + innerHeight (screen measurement) = bottom of screen position.